# Should the data from API be saved to the database or just call API everytime when data is needed for a website

Tags: python, django, database, api, rest

Please assume I have no experience in developing the structure of websites.

I am currently working on a website that displays data fetched from an API. (I use Django and python for the web app)
I want to display the current Covid-19 data and analyze the trend in graphs and charts.
I am able to grab the data from the API, but question is for a site like that needs an update on the numbers on a daily basis, what is the best practice for retrieving data. Should I be saving the api data to my database for easier access or should I just call the API everytime when the web page is visited (which is already a necessity due to the day to day update) and process data? (Performance wise or easily of processing data.)

I would appreciate if anyone would share their experience.

Comment: it depends on both business requirements(including cost) and limits of the api you are using. If it is fine update the data once in an (n minutes) then after fetching from the api - cache it for n minutes. If covid api is super fast and doesn't have any throttling limit then you may not need. It is also related to traffic of your site. No need to make a request to covid api for each user if there are let's say 1000 active users in a second.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have a concern, lets say I use and rely on api call, if I deploy the app, for long term use, would relying on the api data be a disadvantage? I mean if in the future the api response format changes, the site would stop working.

Comment: Good api’s especially(facebook, google etc) doesn’t change their ip formats suddenly. They have versioning, depreciation policies, notifiers(warning messages etc) - but in your case it depends on who is providing covid api. Even you cache the data, when it expires you will make a call again that will cause problems anyway